# PHP remove duplicate values from a multidimensional array

Tags: php

How to remove duplicate values from a multidimensional array.

For example, I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fruit_id] => cea2fc4b4058
            [title] => Apple title one
            [name] => Apple
            [weight] => 22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fruit_id] => sdfsdec4b4058
            [title] => Grapefruit title one
            [name] => Grapefruit 
            [weight] => 19
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fruit_id] => hjkvcbc4b4058
            [title] => Grapefruit title two
            [name] => Grapefruit
            [weight] => 17
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fruit_id] => tyuutcgbfg058
            [title] => Lemon title one
            [name] => Lemon
            [weight] => 15
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [fruit_id] => lkjyurtws4058
            [title] => Mango title
            [name] => Mango
            [weight] => 13
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [fruit_id] => bner3223df058
            [title] => Lemon title two
            [name] => Lemon
            [weight] => 11
        )
)
```

In this array, I need to leave only one fruit with the maximum weight.
I want to save all the data, but at the same time remove duplicate fruits.
Thank.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: I tried this method it did not change the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by `weight` ascending and then create a result using the `name` as the key so the ones with larger `weight` will overwrite the smaller `weight` ones:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'weight'), SORT_ASC, $array);
foreach($array as $v) { $result[$v['name']] = $v; }
```

Then if you want to re-index (not required):

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `array_unique($array);` code